# demorar pra gerar um pdf com o mPDF Kartik para Yii2

Tags: pdf, yii, mpdf

Estou gerando um pdf com 41 e esta demorando cerca de 3 minutos, teria a possibilidade de gerar esse arquivo mais rapido?

segue o código:

```
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        // set to use core fonts only
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
        // A4 paper format
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        // portrait orientation
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        // stream to browser inline
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        // your html content input
        'content' => $content,
        // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
        // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        // any css to be embedded if required
        'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:14px}',
        // set mPDF properties on the fly
        'options' => ['title' => 'Relatório de plano de contas'],
        'defaultFontSize' => 3,
        'marginLeft' => 10,
        'marginRight' => 10,
        'marginTop' => 30,
        'marginBottom' => 11,
        'marginHeader' => 6,
        'marginFooter' => 6,
        // call mPDF methods on the fly
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader' => [$header],
            'SetFooter' => ['<p style="text-align: center;font-size: 8px;">Documento emitido pelo Mono Sistemas Gestão Empresarial. Todos os Direitos Reservados © www.monosistemas.com.br</p>'],
        ]
    ]);
    $pdfName = 'PLANO_DE_CONTAS-_' . date('d-m-Y') . '.pdf';

    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_HTML;
    Yii::$app->response->setDownloadHeaders($pdfName, 'application/pdf');

    return $pdf->render();

}
```

Comment: 41 páginas? Tente atualizar o PHP para uma versão mais moderna (especialmente a versão 7, que ainda não foi lançada em sua versão de produção). Ou analise se há algum recurso na sua hospedagem que esta te limitando (principalmente processador e RAM).

Comment: Então, eu acredito que o problema seja a a formatação das paginas, quando retiro o css, o tempo diminui bastante. Mas mesmo assim fica muito elevado (1min). O servidor é local então não é problema com hospedagem,e o php esta em sua ultima versão em produção.

Comment: Neste caso provavelmente não há o que fazer. Talvez com o PHP 7 melhore, mas não deve melhorar o suficiente. Não vejo alternativa além de substituir por outra ferramenta menos intensiva que o mPDF ou uma ferramenta nativa, como o WkHtmlToPdf.